# IONOS fails to find links in index page

Tags: html

there is a homepage in IONOS which lies in the directory :

`/html_archive/web.archive.org/web/20230401023xxx/http_/test-group.com`

A lot of links are found like the logo and it is also displayed .

```
<img class="sp-default-logo hidden-xs" src="../../../20221006224xxxim_/http_/www.test-group.com/images/logos/test-test-logo.png" alt="test">
```

When I create a folder **/html_archive/WebsiteTesttin** with the same **index.html** and I change the *.png path to

```
../web.archive.org/web/20230401023xxx/http_/test-group.com/test-test-logo.png
```

The image can't be found .

Only images in .../ can be found.

Anyone a idea?

Thank you.

Goal is to not have such a complicated main page link.

it should be more like: [www.test-page.com/page1.html](http://www.test-page.com/page1.html)

thank you. let me know if should describe more!

I was expecting, that the links will work . because it would make sense..

it think something is blocking the index.html from calling the links

Comment: I just downloaded the website with the working links with right click.. and then put it into  /html_archive/WebsiteTesttin    and now I can see that the links are working better now - like the css is formatting the page nice